# Sonarqube Source error in jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to analyze my project with sonarqube scanner in Jenkins. However when I'm building job it's always reporting some kind of an error, more exactly:

```
INFO: Option -e/--errors is no longer supported and will be ignored
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarScanner1/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
INFO: Java 1.8.0_151 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs amd64
INFO: User cache: /var/jenkins_home/.sonar/cache
INFO: Publish mode
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=232ms
INFO: Server id: AWEptYvpPRWpK4xbT0G4
INFO: User cache: /var/jenkins_home/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=124ms
INFO: SonarQube server 6.7.1
INFO: Default locale: "en", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Process project properties
ERROR: Invalid value of sonar.sources for test
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 3.218s
INFO: Final Memory: 42M/114M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: The folder 'polacpat/Documents/Jenkins2/workspace/SonarScanningTestProject/src/test' does not exist for 'test' (base directory = /var/jenkins_home/workspace/SonarScanningTestProject)
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Those are my Sonarqube analysis properties 
[AnalysisProperties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahngr.png)

This is location of my project, it's automatically created because code is from gitlab...

[Project Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FMii.png)

Now I don't really understand how does this work and how should I configure it. I have added the same name to a new sonarqube project and also sonarqube project key I have created within a sonarqube which is connected with a jenkins to those analyse properties in here, I don't understand how exactly does this works...

Updated folder:
[Wrong Folder Being Analysed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAn2D.png)

Updated second error log after trying to set: *sonar.sources=./src* or
  *sonar.sources=./src/main*

```
11:19:28.650 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property
    at org.sonar.java.JavaClasspath.init(JavaClasspath.java:59)
    at org.sonar.java.AbstractJavaClasspath.getElements(AbstractJavaClasspath.java:281)
    at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.getJavaClasspath(SonarComponents.java:141)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.<init>(JavaSquid.java:83)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:83)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:88)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:180)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:288)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:283)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecuteTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:111)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
11:19:28.651 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
11:19:28.656 DEBUG: Execution stop
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Invalid value of sonar.sources for test"

sonar.sources must be relative to worskspace

```
sonar.sources=./src/test
```

And 
*Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property*
means you need set sonar.java.binaries pointing to binaries

```
sonar.java.binaries=target/classes
```

See [sonar paramenters](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters)

Comment: Analysis is triggered, there is however other problem. It's not analysing all of mine java classes which are in main folder, it's analysing only some auto generated test folder in which there is a one auto generated JUnit class. I want it to analyse my main folder with all of the java classes. It's build with maven, could that be a problem ? Photo in top post.

Comment: sonar.sources=./src to test all or sonar.sources=./src/main to only main. Easy peasy

Comment: I tried to do that already and then It throws me an error. Posting second error log to the post.I think it has something to do with a fact that my project is with a maven.

Comment: Don't you please know where is the problem in that ?